# Python - What does my XML contain?

Tags: python, xml

I'm new to this whole Python-universe, but have decided to start out by learning how to handle open data-formats, primarily XML for starters.

I have encountered a problem where I cannot figure out how I get an overview of a parsed .XML-file.

The example I'm following would have me do this:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
    doc = parse('rt22.xml')

    for bus in doc.findall('bus'):
```

This means parsing the .XML I have written myself, and then, in this example, start looking for an element with a certain name.

The example knows that there's something called "bus" in the XML-file, but now that I've found and parsed my own XML-file, I don't know what it contains.

If I just open it with a texteditor, I get to see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<TilOgFraflytninger>
  <row>
    <TilOgFraflytningId>1</TilOgFraflytningId>
    <LejemaalId>1</LejemaalId>
    <AfdId>1</AfdId>
    <SelId>1</SelId>
    <TilFlyttet>1954-08-01T00:00:00</TilFlyttet>
    <FraFlyttet>2010-05-15T00:00:00</FraFlyttet>
  </row>
  <row>
    <TilOgFraflytningId>2</TilOgFraflytningId>
    <LejemaalId>1</LejemaalId>
    <AfdId>1</AfdId>
    <SelId>1</SelId>
    <TilFlyttet>2010-06-15T00:00:00</TilFlyttet>
    <FraFlyttet>2013-11-28T00:00:00</FraFlyttet>
  </row>
</TilOgFraflytninger>
```

But how would I get that information (that something is called "AfdId" etc.) without having to open the XML in a text editor?

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) ought to be a good start -- for example, [19.7.1.3. Finding interesting elements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements).

Comment: Wow, I already went through the documentation. Can't see how I missed this... Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, your sample document is not valid XML.

Comment: Sylvian: I have thousands of lines of code. And the correct XML-header I think. Sorry for the bad example. I will edit the question.

Comment: This question is not unclear. It might be a bit wordy but I think it's perfectly clear that the problem is that OP doesn't know the name of the tags and still want to be able to go through the XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways comes to mind:

First, [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) shows an example of the `iter` function, as pointed out by Jongware:

```
>>> for neighbor in root.iter('neighbor'):
...   print neighbor.attrib
...
{'name': 'Austria', 'direction': 'E'}
{'name': 'Switzerland', 'direction': 'W'}
{'name': 'Malaysia', 'direction': 'N'}
{'name': 'Costa Rica', 'direction': 'W'}
{'name': 'Colombia', 'direction': 'E'}
```

Note that the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) function takes an optional `tag` argument (in this case `'neighbor'`) that is used to filter what is iterated over. If left out it will DFS through *all* nodes starting at the root.

You could also use [XPath syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) to match all elements, e.g.:

```
elems = root.findall('.//*') # returns a list
for e in elems:
    print(e.tag)
```

which would match all element nodes starting at `root`. Actually, you can skip the asterisk since `.//` will do the same thing. And `./` would match elements one level below the root.

Comment: I'm working with the Element.iter function right now, but the problem is that it again requires of me that I know that the XML contains a 'neighbor-item'...

Comment: The tag argument is optional. Just leave it out. Here's the documentation: [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter). Also note that it does a DFS. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I've gotten my code to iterate through the XML-file now, but all it prints is several hundred lines of "{}"-brackets. No contents. I've tried giving it different tags and so on, but it only prints the brackets - never the contents of the any of the elements in the rows.

Comment: Are you printing `attrib`? That's a dictionary of a tag's attributes. Try printing `tag` or `text` instead. `tag` is the tag name, and text is its content. Check out the sample XML in the docs to see what's being printed in the above example.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm using the .attrib function and should be using the .tag function instead! So now, I've gotten it to tell me which .tags I can lookup, and by printing .text, I'm able to find the values of all kinds of a certain tag. Now I just need to learn the correct terms so I can actually communicate what the heck I'm doing... 

EDIT: Looks like you beat me to it :)

Comment: One terminology pointer: attrib, tag and text aren't functions, they're just variables.